# Establishing bounds on Regressing Y on X versus regressing X on Y

Tags: regression

Let's say we are performing simple linear regression of $y =b_1x + b_0$. Assume we estimate $b_1 = c$, we can use $c = 2$ for this example. When we consider the flipped regression of $x =b_1'y + b_0'$ can we establish any upper or lower bound on $b_1'$? Other than it being greater than 0?? This is the only thing I can think of because we know if $b_1 = 2, cov(x,y) > 0$

Comment: The interpretation of this question, and therefore what the correct answer is, depend on what you mean by "know $b_1=c:$" are you referring to the *actual parameters* (which in practice are unknown) or to *estimates based on data?*

Comment: You might find the answers to [Effect of switching...](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20553/6633) to  be helpful.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22718 is a very highly voted thread that shows the answer.  For more like this, please search our site for [switch x y regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20switch%20x%20y&searchOn=3).

Answer (score 3):

The equation of Regression Line, $y$ on $x$, in its explicit form reads

$$
y= r \frac{SD_y}{SD_x} x + \bar{y} - r\frac{SD_x}{SD_x} \bar{x}$$

And the question has provided us the coefficient of $x$ in the above equation to be equal to $c$, and that is given to be positive. That implies,
$$
r\frac{SD_y}{SD_x} =c$$
$$\frac{SD_x}{SD_y} = r/c$$
$$r \frac{SD_x}{SD_y} = r^2/c$$

The equation of Regression Line, x on y, is simply obtained by replacing all y’s with x’s, thus,
$$
x= r \frac{SD_x}{SD_y} y + \bar{x} - r\frac{SD_x}{SD_y} \bar{y}$$

Using the notations given in the question, we have:
$$
b_1’ = r\frac{SD_x}{SD_y} = r^2/c$$
Since,
$$|r| \leq 1 \implies r^2 \leq 1$$
$$ r^2/c \leq 1/c$$
Thus,
$$ b_1’ \leq 1/c$$